# Synergy dropping certain keys

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, kvm-switch, synergy

I'm having a very strange problem with synergy.  I'm running a synergy server instance on an Ubuntu machine and a synergy client on an adjacent Windows XP machine.  On occasion certain letters on the keyboard will stop working on the Windows machine (they are always the same ones "c" and "h" for example).  Closing and reopening individual applications (on the Windows machine) will make the problem go away for that application, including Firefox, text editors, and even explorer.exe.  Restarting the server also fixes the problem.  I see no issues reported on the lowest log settings and I can't seem to figure out what triggers it.  Any ideas?  Or has anyone a solution for this problem?

Comment: Oh my God, I have the same problem now, 5 years later, between Windows 8 (as server) and Windows 7 (client), with letters "c", "h" and "v". Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a long time with the exact same setup. I moved my syergy server to my windows box and just put 'synergyc (hostname)' in my startup scripts on my ubuntu box. I have had 0 problems since them. Synergy server on the linux side seems to not be nearly as mature as it is on the windows platform, however the synergy client runs flawlessly for my on rhel and ubuntu.